# Where do I find an exterior plumbing box?

Tags: plumbing

We had to break the stucco on the second story exterior to replace the shower/tub valve.  I need a box with a cover to replace the stucco so it can be accessed at a later date.

Where would I find something like this?

Comment: Where do you live?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? You should have full access through the escutcheon plate for valve & shut-offs. Access panels aren't actually there for re-plumbing, since the plumbing's good for 100-years.

Access panels were there in the old days because valves didn't have cartridges & needed access for servicing & for operating shut-off valves, not that much of anything had local shut-offs back then. You rarely see access panels anywhere anymore because of the took way-way too long technology.

Otherwise, if you want one get just a panel cover at the store so you can insulate the valve. Instead of possibly having no ability to insulate with a tight shallow box of some kind.